# How to use ExternalFile field in Solr

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, apache, solr, solrnet

I am using External File field in solr for my frequently updated types of data. I had created a file external `_mycustomfield` in my Index directory and I had created new field in `Schema.xml` as:

```
<fieldType name="mycustomfield" class="solr.ExternalFileField" keyField="Id" defVal="1" indexed="false" stored="false" valType="float"/>

<field name="MyField" type="mycustomfield" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

But I get an error in `SolrCore` which is:

> Testcore: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core Testcore: Unknown fieldType 'mycustomfield' specified on field MyField. Schema file is C:\hds-4.10.1\solr-4.10.1\server\solr\Testcore\conf\schema.xml

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Your file should be `external_MyField` and not `external_mycustomfield`.

Comment: But still solr core throws above mentioned error.

Comment: Your `fieldType` and `field` definitions look fine. Can you post your entire schema.xml so we can check if something else is wrong?

Comment: Thank you. My issue is resolved now. I have added "fieldType" at wrong place that's why it throws error.

Comment: Can you help me how to write value to external file?

Comment: You can see a blog post I wrote about this: http://www.openjems.com/solr-external-file-fields/

Comment: I have already follow that blog and i think it is about "Replicating EFFs". but my question is how this externalfilefield file is updated from my application?

Comment: Is there any way to update this file which is located on solr directory? or key-value pair in this externalFileField is updated on what bases?

Comment: My application and Solr Server were physically separated on two place.
Application will calculate a score and generate a file for
ExternalFileField. for this Is there any way how to implement?

Comment: Is there any way to post external file in solr directory?

Comment: These should be in a separate question.

Comment: Yes, here is separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412859/how-to-write-externalfilefield-value-to-external-file-in-solr