# How to update ExternalFileField value to external file which is located on solr directory

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, apache, solr, solrnet

I have implemented ExternalFileField in solr. But I am not able to update values into external file "**external_BestSellerTest**" that is located into ~\data directory inside solr core.

My application and Solr Server were physically separated on two place. Application will calculate a score and generate a file for ExternalFileField. So, Am I need to post this external file into solr directory.

Help me to update values into that external file.

Comment: How are you trying to write to the file? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Is there any way to update this file which is located on solr directory? or key-value pair in this externalFileField is updated on what bases? My application and Solr Server were physically separated on two place. Application will calculate a score and generate a file for ExternalFileField. for this Is there any way how to implement?